# float left isn't expanding in IE6

Tags: html, css

i have css code, im using float to expand left   *column a*   and right  *column b*  .

i would like to expand left *column a* dynamically as i put content in right *column b*.

but this isn't happening in my browser IE. its working in       http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/3/ but not in my browser IE 9,8,7,6 but IE 10 working fine..

## css code

```
.container {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
}

.left {
width: 45%;
float: left;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 lightblue;  
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}

.right {
width: 45%;
float: right;

}
```

## html code

```
<div class = "container">
<div class="left">
column a
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
</div>


<div class="right">
column b<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />dynamic row<br />dynamic row<br />dynamic row<br />dynamic row<br />dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />
columnb <br />


</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: IE6? You poor soul.

Comment: the css code isn't working in IE9,8,7,6 but 10 is working fine..

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what it's supposed to look like and what it looks like in IE?  Because Chrome and IE9 are both showing me the exact same thing.

Comment: It __can't__ work. [jsFiddle doesn't support IE6](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/faq.html) anymore!

Comment: @Marc Audet, the css code isn't working in IE6,7,8,9, but IE 10 working fine.

Comment: I just tried your fiddle in IE10 using various browser/document modes and everything seems to work.  There must be some other CSS conflict in the style sheets causing the issue.

Comment: @ Marc Aude, if i remove height:100%; it will work in IE10 but not IE6,7,8,9

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, with out sending screen shot ill explain for you column b it supposed to show all its content with left float color blue, but this isn't working, in IE6,7,8,9 in IE10 its working if i remove   height:100%;

Comment: @hadi: So, what's wrong with leaving `height: 100%`?  Does it work in IE9 *with* that?  I'm a little confused here.  (I don't have IE10 to test with, but it seems to look right in IE9 *with* `height:100%`)

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat, no doesn't  work in IE9,8,7,6 but IE 10 working fine it show all its content of column b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have updated the code in JSFiddle, (note : i have also include jquery), you need to include that javascript.

It has been tested in IE6 also. So, it will work in other browsers too.

```
check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/btCQn/1/

<style>
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
    position:relative;

}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 lightblue;
  position:absolute;
}

.right {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;

}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".left").css("height",$(".right").height());
});
</script>
```

Its working

Comment: If its working, can u please accept the answer and do upvote?